How to deploy Google Cloud Functions (v1) without Cloud Source Repositories?
I'm running into an issue with my new client where I used to rely on Cloud Source Repositories connected to a private GitHub repository for my previous clients. After selecting the repo and subdirectory, I could easily deploy Google Functions v1, and everything worked fine.
However, since Cloud Source Repositories has been shut down, I am now stuck. For my new client, I've tried integrating through Cloud Build with both first and second generation options, but I can't seem to find the right way to connect the repository and deploy the Google Function (v1) properly.
Additionally, when I attempt to use Google Functions v2, I don't even see an option to retrieve the code directly from a repository.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? How do you manage to deploy Google Functions without Cloud Source Repositories? Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Please have a look at the document1 and this document2.

Seems to exactly match my need. I'll look at it and be right back. Thanks !

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided comment has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.
